# separate real and imaginary part of a complex number in python

Tags: python, object, arguments, filenames, definition

I have need to extract the real and imaginary elements of a complex number in python.  I know how to make a list into a complex number... but not the other way around.

I have this:

```
Y = (-5.79829066331+4.55640490659j)
```

I need:

```
Z = (-5.79829066331, 4.55640490659)
```

and I will also need each part if there is a way to go directly without going by way of Z:

```
A = -5.79829066331
B = 4.55640490659
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#complex

Thanks!

Answer (score 56):

```
Y = (-5.79829066331+4.55640490659j)

Z = (Y.real, Y.imag)

A = Y.real
B = Y.imag
```

---

**BTW:**

More: [Python: Complex number - real and imaginary part](https://blog.furas.pl/python-complex-number-real-and-imaginary-part-gb.html)

Comment: I add it to blog [Python: Complex number - real and imaginary part](https://blog.furas.pl/python-complex-number-real-and-imaginary-part-gb.html)

Answer (score 17):

```
Z = (Y.real, Y.imag)
A = Y.real
B = Y.imag
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   import numpy as np                 #Can be done easily using Numpy Lib
   array=np.array([3,4.5,3 + 5j,0])   #Initialize complex array
   real=np.isreal(array)              #Boolean condition for real part
   real_array=array[real]             #Storing it in variable using boolean indexing
   imag=np.iscomplex(array)           #Boolean condition for real part
   imag_array=array[imag]             #Storing it in variable using boolean indexing
   print(real)
   print(imag)
   print(real_array)
   print(imag_array)
```