# complex number to polar form in python

Tags: python-2.7, math

I'm new to python so please bear with me. 
The problem is:

"Write a function polar(z) to convert a complex number to its polar form (r,theta). You may use the math.atan2 and math.hypot functions but not the cmath library."

I don't even know where to start with this one, but so far I have:

```
import math
def polar(z):
    z = a + bj
    r = math.hypot(a,b)
    theta = math.atan2(b,a)
    print "(",r,",",theta,")"
```

Any help will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use object.real and object.imag to get the values of real and imaginary values. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592803/separate-real-and-imaginary-part-of-a-complex-number-in-python)

```
import math
def polar(z):
    a= z.real
    b= z.imag
    r = math.hypot(a,b)
    theta = math.atan2(b,a)
    return r,theta # use return instead of print.

u=3+5j
print polar(u)
```

Output:

`(5.830951894845301, 1.0303768265243125)`

Read difference b/w print and return in functions.